# Azure DevOps clean download folder before run

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a deployment job like this:

```
jobs:
  - deployment:
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: build
              artifact: Packages
```

This downloads artifacts to `C:\a\1\build\Packages`, with `C:\a\1` being `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`.

Due to `clean: all` I would expect everything under `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` (`C:\a\1`) to be deleted on every run of this pipeline. However this is not the case, as a subsequent of this pipeline will fail due to previous downloads still being present:

```
##[error]Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: C:\a\1\build\Packages\FunctionApp.*.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.
```

Is there something off with my configuration, or how can I clean the download folder before downloading?